# Joomla 3.8 compatablity with MYSQL 5.6 , 5.7 and 8

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0, mysql-5.7, joomla3.8

I currently have setup Joomla 3.9.3 on production with MYSQL 5.5.62, i would like to upgrade to 5.7 or 8.

Is joomla 3.9.x Compatible with MySQL 5.6, 5.7, 8. The official documentation states that joomla works with 5.5.X+. Though this may imply supporting of 5.6, but wonder why they have stated their support on a minor version rather than a major one like 5.5+

Just need a confirmation on the same and any official  supporting documents if available

Comment: See the link https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements

Comment: This is a better question for the joomla se site [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had a Joomla v3.9.4 site running on MySQL 5.7.25 for several months and all has been good. No issues with Joomla or the extensions we're running that I've noticed.

Good luck!